# Can't get GPU support for Docker with WSL2

Tags: docker, nvidia-graphics-card, windows-subsystem-for-linux, docker-for-windows, wsl2

Trying to run a GPU enabled container such as:

`docker run --gpus all nvcr.io/nvidia/k8s/cuda-sample:nbody nbody -gpu -benchmark`

I get this error:

```
docker: Error response from daemon: OCI runtime create failed: container_linux.go:367: starting container process caused: process_linux.go:495: container init caused: Running hook #0:: error running hook: exit status 1, stdout: , stderr: nvidia-container-cli: initialization error: driver error: failed to process request: unknown.
ERRO[0025] error waiting for container: context canceled
```

Running a non-GPU container such as `docker run hello-world` works fine.

- I did enable WSL integration in Docker Desktop settings
- Windows 10 Pro (version 20H2 build 19042.985)
- Docker Desktop 3.3.3 (64133), engine 20.10.6, compose 1.29.1
- WSL2 with Ubuntu 20.04
- Nvidia driver 470.14 + CUDA 11.3
- Running on a local laptop with Geforce RTX 2070 Max-Q

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Can't get GPU support for Docker with WSL2
>
> - Windows 10 Pro (version 20H2 build 19042.985)

[CUDA within WSL2 requirements are a higher Windows build than you are running.](https://docs.nvidia.com/cuda/wsl-user-guide/index.html#installing-nvidia-drivers).  You will have to upgrade to a supported Windows Insider build to achieve your goal

> Ensure that you install Build version 20145 or higher. [We recommend being on WIP OS 21332 and higher with Linux Kernel 5.4.91+ for the best performance.](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/wsl/install-win10)
> You can check your build version number by running winver via the Windows Run command.

Additionally:

> Ensure you have the latest kernel by clicking “Check for updates” in the “Windows Update” section of the Settings app. If the right update with the kernel 4.19.121+ is installed, you should be able to see it in the Windows Update history. Alternatively, you can check the version number by running the following command in PowerShell:
> `wsl cat /proc/version`

Comment: Switching to the Dev channel, which could potentially be unstable, sounds like too big a cost. I'll stick with dual boot for now. Any idea on when this would get into mainstream Windows builds?

Comment: @MichaelLitvin - Whenever the build is higher than 20145